# Image Picker Flutter and Progress Indicator

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I have implmented [image picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker), it is working great on both ios and android.

However, after i have captured an image, it is taking quite long for it to appear on my Image.file(image) widget.

I cannot decrease the quality of image, as it matters in the app.

So i need something like [CachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) but to load from file, not from internet, any ideas?

I just want to show an progress bar or indicator, just to let the user know that there is a process.

```
File? image;

Future pickImage(ImageSource source, BuildContext context) async {
try {

      final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);

      if (image == null) return;
      var imageTemporary = File(image.path);

      if (source == ImageSource.camera) {
        final img.Image? capturedImage =
            img.decodeImage(await File(image.path).readAsBytes());
        final img.Image orientedImage = img.bakeOrientation(capturedImage!);
        imageTemporary =
            await File(image.path).writeAsBytes(img.encodeJpg(orientedImage));
      }
      setState(() {
        this.image = imageTemporary;
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {print(e.toString());}
  }
```

Thats my function to call image picker.

And passing it to ElevatedButton like:

Comment: You can use a `LinearProgressIndicator` or a `CircularProgresssIndicator` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-rhXZLtpv0